# Query taking too long for billions of records in Hive

Tags: hive, query-optimization

I have a Hive table having `size: 326.8 MB` and `Number of records: 2,012,402,223`. As number of rows are only 10 so file size is not too big, but number of rows is too High.
While executing a simple 'Select query' for this table process is stuck at Mappers.
I tried increasing number of mappers as well with below properties, but it's still stuck.

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize= 2684354;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize= 2684354;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.node= 2684354;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.rack= 2684354;
```

Please suggest on Query Optimization.

Comment: How does your "simple select query" look like?

Comment: select id, <case when .. then 1 else 0 end> as value from table ;